# Having trouble installing WinAppleKey Driver from Github page

Tags: driver

I want to be able to capture input from the Fn and Eject keys on my Apple magic keyboard when using it with a Windows 10 machine. To do this, I came across an open source driver called WinAppleKey (https://github.com/samartzidis/WinAppleKey). The readme mentions a setup.**msi** file, which I could not locate in the repo after downloading it. So how do I actually install the driver?

I've tried running the WinAppleKey.sln file, which has not worked out despite having the latest versions of the WDK and SDK because of the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "SLIST_HEADER" is undefined  WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    16389   
Error (active)  E0035   #error directive: "No target architecture defined"  WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntddk.h  9103    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PDRIVER_EXCPTN_CALLBACK" is undefined   WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntddk.h  13802   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PCMC_EXCEPTION" is undefined    WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntddk.h  13879   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PCPE_EXCEPTION" is undefined    WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntddk.h  13890   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "SLIST_HEADER" is undefined  WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    16409   
Error (active)  E0035   #error directive: "No target architecture defined"  WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    20679   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    23818   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    23887   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    23988   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    23994   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PFN_NUMBER" is undefined    WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    27128   
Error (active)  E0035   #error directive: "No Target Architecture"  WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\ntdef.h  201 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    24001   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined WinAppleKey C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdm.h    23901
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may of already found it, but the setup.msi file is in the release files of the project and not the code source.

Here's where you can download it from : https://github.com/samartzidis/WinAppleKey/releases/tag/v1.0.9

You will just have to click on **setup.msi** to download it onto your PC.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I had not. Thank you for helping out with my noob question :)